# Como exibir todos os arquivos dos commits realizados numa branch?

Tags: git

Há algum comando do git para exibir todos os arquivos, de todos os commits realizados numa branch?

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que poderá te ajudar

"After you have created several commits, or if you have cloned a repository with an existing commit history, you’ll probably want to look back to see what has happened. The most basic and powerful tool to do this is the git log command."

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Comment: Responder (assim como perguntar) em outro idioma não é aconselhável. É interessante você editar, traduzindo a citação, pelo menos.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver!

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar este comando

```
git log myBranch --not master --name-status --pretty=format:"%x09"
```